# I don't understand what's going on with file_exists and scandir

Tags: php, file, preg-match, browser-cache

I'm helping out a friend writing a somewhat sensible caching function for one of his scripts. It's essentially using 9 different SQL queries to fetch leaderboard data (one of which is very taxing)

I came up with the idea to create a cache for it, starting off like this:

```
  // Cache directory
  $cacheDir = "/cache";

  // Path to cache directory
  $cachePath = "/var/www/html/test";

  // Better safe than sorry
  if (!file_exists($cachePath . $cacheDir))
  {
        mkdir($cachePath . $cacheDir, 0777, true);
  }

  // Cache rebuild switches
  $monsterCache = false;
  $pvpCache = false;
  $guildCache = false;

  // Get the size and all files within the cache directory
  $cache = array_slice(scandir($cachePath . $cacheDir), 2);
  $cacheSize = sizeof($cache);
```

Continuing on, I set some switches to determine whether we need to update or not, then fetch all the files and size of the array containing all the files in the cache folder.

I follow up with this:

```
  // Validate the cached files
  if ($cacheSize < 1) {
    // None present. Rebuild all.
    $monsterCache = true;
    $pvpCache = true;
    $guildCache = true;
  } else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cacheSize; $i++) {
      // Check the monster kill cache
      if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+_monster_kills_leaderboard\.php/', $cache[$i], $cacheFile)) {
        if (time() >= explode('_', $cacheFile[0])[0]) {
          unlink($cachePath . $cacheDir . "/{$cache[$i]}");
          $monsterCache = true;
        }
      } else {
        $monsterCache = true;
      }

      // Check the PVP cache
      if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+_pvp_leaderboard\.php/', $cache[$i], $cacheFile)) {
        if (time() >= explode('_', $cacheFile[0])[0]) {
          unlink($cachePath . $cacheDir . "/{$cache[$i]}");
          $pvpCache = true;
        }
      } else {
        $pvpCache = true;
      }

      // Check the Castle Guild leader cache
      if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+_guild_leader\.php/', $cache[$i], $cacheFile)) {
        if (time() >= explode('_', $cacheFile[0])[0]) {
          unlink($cachePath . $cacheDir . "/{$cache[$i]}");
          $guildCache = true;
        }
      } else {
        $guildCache = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

What I do is upon creating and writing the cache file, I'm appending a unix timestamp to represent how long it is valid, split it from the file name and compare the current time to that of the timestamp to determine whether to remove the file and re-create it. (*timestamp_pvp_leaderboard.php*)

I'm writing to the files like this:

```
  if ($monsterCache) {
    $monsterCache = false;

    // This decides how long the cache is valid
    // Updates every hour from initialization.
    $cacheTTL = strtotime('+1 Hour', time());

    // Fetch the monster data
    <snip>

    // Construct data
    $data = array(
      'Name, Kills' => $result[0]->__get("name") . ', ' . $result[0]->__get("kills"),
      'Name, Kills' => $result[1]->__get("name") . ', ' . $result[1]->__get("kills"),
      'Name, Kills' => $result[2]->__get("name") . ', ' . $result[2]->__get("kills")
    );

    // Populate the cache
    foreach($data as $key => $val) {
      file_put_contents($cachePath . $cacheDir . "/{$cacheTTL}_monster_kills_leaderboard.php", $key.', '.$val.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
  }
```

This works all fine on my computer, using multiple browsers sitting on the page and spamming refresh, however the second something touches the cache file (like reading to it the first time, or opening it while the script is live) the file itself get spammed with additions. It's the same 3 fields repeating itself.

I've tried a few different approaches so far, but I absolutely can't figure out what's going on.

Have anyone else encountered this before? How did you solve it?
What am I doing wrong or missing here?

I'll continue to look at it later today, but thanks in advance for any insight! It's been a while since I dabbed with PHP at all unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try using any existing cache system, APC for example. It allows you to set (with needed TTL) and get mostly any data. It is very reliable and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't know something like that already existed (except for memcached), I'll give it a spin.